# Splitting of filename in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to `split` the filename and get the last path of the string in javascript.

For example the path is `D://Smita//GMAP//Images//images.jpg` , but according to my requirement it should be `Images/images.jpg` How to acheive this using javascript?

Comment: Use `split()`, take the last two elements of the array, and join them.

Comment: can u giv me an example please

Comment: See Fabricio Matte's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var path = 'D://Smita//GMAP//Images//images.jpg'.split('//').slice(-2).join('/');
//path is "Images/images.jpg"
```

---

For a Google Maps info window you should be able to throw it as the `src` of an `img` element:

```
content: '<img src="'+path+'">'
```

See related [How to add an image to InfoWindow of marker in google maps v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161013/how-to-add-an-image-to-infowindow-of-marker-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: can u help me how to display image in google map infowindow. From database i am geeting the path as D://Smita//GMAP//Images//images.jpg but no image is displayed rather path is displaying

Comment: @user1749062 I believe you can just put it as the `src` of an `<img>` tag, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161077/1331430