# GoogleMaps api: How to place images in the content of Multiple InfoWindows?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, google-maps, infowindow

In brief, I want to combine these two topics:

[How to add an image to InfoWindow of marker in google maps v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161013/how-to-add-an-image-to-infowindow-of-marker-in-google-maps-v3)

[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

I have my location data stored in a database and it is retrieved as an array. I want to place a marker and infowindow for each of the x amount of locations in the database. One of fields contains an Image and I want to include this in the infoWindow  content.

Here is where I am so far:

Php:
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("*******","*******","*******","tests");

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Name, Latitude, Longitude, Image FROM locate_coords");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$users[]= $row;

}
```

Javascript `function initialize()`:

```
<?php
$js_array = json_encode($users);
echo "var locations = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>

var styles = [
   {
     stylers: [
       { hue: "#00ffe6" },
       { saturation: -20 },
     ]
   },{
     featureType: "road",
     elementType: "geometry",
     stylers: [
       { lightness: 100 },
       { visibility: "simplified" },
     ]
   },{
     featureType: "road",
     elementType: "labels",
     stylers: [
       { visibility: "off" }
     ]
   }
 ];

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
   {name: "Styled Map"});

var mapProp = {
   zoom: 12,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
   mapTypeControlOptions: {
     mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
   }
 };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
   mapProp);


   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var marker, i;

   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

    //var container = document.getElementById("photo");

    //var img = new Image();
    //img.src = '
    //container.appendChild(img);

     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
       map: map
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
       return function() {
        //infowindow.setContent('<img id=="photo">' + locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.setContent('<img src=/uploads/'. locations[i][3]'>' + locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
       }
     })(marker, i));

   }

map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Putting a normal image url in works nicely,  but as soon as I try putting an array value, the map doesn't want to load! At this point, I really could do with a sane head to tell me what to do :-(..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in the line

```
infowindow.setContent('<img src=/uploads/'. locations[i][3]'>' + locations[i][0]);
```

. is not the concatenation operator and between `locations[i][3]'>'` there is no concatenation operator at all. The correct code would be:

```
infowindow.setContent('<img src=/uploads/' + locations[i][3] + '>' + locations[i][0]);
```

Comment: Oh my days! I knew it would be something minuscule like that! Thanks SO much!! Thats made me very happy/relieved. I wish I could vote you up but I have to have 15 rep apparently.